# Combinatorics probability.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

What is the probability of getting Three face cards not all in the same suit, and any four non-face cards?

Not to sure how to work this one out.

EDIT: Got it figured out now thanks guys!

Comment: How many cards do you get, and from what exactly? Your information is lacking.

Comment: Standard 52 card deck. Apologies.

Comment: @JAmesRean I'm happy for you that you could solve your problem. Could you please post your answer here (or accept an answer that helped you to solve the problem)? This would be good for your question (and for potentially other user that have the same problem).

Comment: I'll do whatever I want so piss off.

Answer (score 1):

[assuming I understood your question]
If 'face cards' are K, Q, J, then you only have 4 outcomes for 'three face cards' in the same suit, hence you have $\binom{12}{3} - 4$ successful outcomes for the first three cards. The rest should be easy.

Comment: NVM I see my error

Comment: There are a total of $\binom{12}{3}$ choices from 12 face cards. 4 of them are wrong (all three cards are of the same suit, there are 4 suits in all). Hence...

Comment: Yep I got it now, so just multiply by the number of choices for the non-face cards namely $40C4$ and then divide by the total number of choices namely $\frac{52!}{45!}$ Thanks.

Comment: The total number of choices is $\binom{52}{7}$